# Dynamically Change iOS Nav Bar Color (Dark Mode)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to implement a toggle for dark mode in my app - this would involve toggling the nav bar color to black when the `UIViewController` is already visible on the screen. I'm aware of how to do this by setting

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

in the AppDelegate, however, this won't work in this case as it needs to be done dynamically.

I've also tried `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white` but this doesn't work either.

UPDATE:

I think a lot of the responses were confused with the purpose of this question - this is NOT at all related to the iOS13 Dark Mode which was just released - it is an INDEPENDENT dark mode feature I want to add to my app (similar to other apps like Messenger etc which had dark mode available IN-APP before iOS 13 was released). What I need to do is dynamically update the color of the UINavigationBar AFTER it has been already displayed on the screen, the same way I can change the background color of a view by doing `view.backgroundColor = .white` and this will update the color in real-time on screen.

Comment: You can check this out for UINavigationBar changes in iOS13 
https://sarunw.com/posts/uinavigationbar-changes-in-ios13.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved this by making the nav bar translucent (in `AppDelegate`):

```
let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
barAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: appRed]
barAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
barAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
barAppearance.isTranslucent = true
```

Next I create a view and place it behind the nav bar as follows (using SnapKit):

```
let coverView = UIView() 
cover.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in
        make.left.right.top.equalTo(self)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.snp.top).offset(universalNumber(num: parent!.topbarHeight))
}
```

where the `parent` is my `UIViewController` and `topBarHeight` is:

```
extension UIViewController {
/**
 *  Height of status bar + navigation bar (if navigation bar exist)
 */
    var topbarHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

Finally, to update the color I set

```
coverView.backgroundColor = universalWhite()
```

where

```
func universalWhite() -> UIColor {
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   let darkMode = defaults.bool(forKey: "darkMode")
   if darkMode {
       return .black
   } else {
       return .white
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the traits provided with the UIViewController to determine the current Interface style, instead of a manual check for versions running iOS 13+. Using this method, you can define colors in your Assets folder for both appearances.

For below iOS 13, you can use something similar to what @byaruah stated, but that is not a global effect. You should also consider using the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` functionality for a global approach.